# Меню на сайте как у Wildberries

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Как сделать *меню* таким образом, чтобы было несколько горизонтальных пунктов, и при наведении на них выпадало не подменю как в обычном dropdown, а подменю из нескольких колонок, содержащих по несколько пунктов в каждой. Если меню организовывается списками, то горизонтальными пунктами должны быть элементы списка, но как в них вложить блок из нескольких колонок с подпунктами непонятно.

Например, так меню сделано на сайте *Wildberries* или *Eldorado*

**Обновление**

У меня обычная верстка, Semantic UI использую, но там такого нет. Вопрос именно в стилях, как вложенный список делается из нескольких колонок. Сейчас они идут все в одну колонку, а подпунктов там 20, не очень красиво выходит.

Comment: Нет ни чего проще, возьмите код с того или другого сайта.

Comment: Вам для какойто cms надо или вы просто верстку делаете ?

Comment: @сергей тамбовцев смотрите там примерно следуюший код
`<ul>
     <li><a href="#">Первое меню</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Второе меню</a>
          <ul>
               <li><a href="#">one</li>
                <li><a href="#">two</li>
              <li><a href="#">three</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
    <li>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">one</li>
                <li><a href="#">two</li>
              <li><a href="#">three</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
<ul>` ну а дальше стилями или вопрос именно в стилях ?

Comment: вопрос именно в стилях, не могу понять, как расположить рядом два ul, которые вложенные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно приблизительно такая структура:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;

} 
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;

}

ul li > div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2
}
ul li:hover > div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li > div > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li > div > ul:first-child {
  background:yellow
}
ul li > div > ul:last-child {
  background: blue;
}
```

и HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Option 1
  <div>
<ul>
  <li>SubOption 1</li>
  <li>SubOption 2</li>
  <li>SubOption 3</li>
</ul>
    <ul>
  <li>SubOption 4</li>
  <li>SubOption 5</li>
  <li>SubOption 6</li>
</ul>  
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

И пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1c7xoey/).